# Avoiding while loop in a shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a data file with 10 minute interval. However the minute and hour information are not correctly written. Also the hour needs to be added by 3 hours.

My file is quite long with 2 years of data. My script is reading each line one by one through a while loop. So it is taking a lot of time. I would like to avoid the while loop to execute it quickly.

```
#!/bin/sh
#----------------------------
#INPUT FILE

#1st col: Year, 2nd: Month, 3rd: Day, 4th: hour, 5&6th: Value of A and B
cat << EOF > ifile.txt
17      01      01      00      3.3   -6.06
17      01      01      00      2.3   -7.8
17      01      01      00      3.13  -7.9
17      01      01      00      4.3   -8.0
17      01      01      00      4.4   -8.1
17      01      01      00      4.4   -8.1
17      01      01      00      1.8   -8.2
17      01      01      00      1.8   -8.2
17      01      01      00      6.3   -8.1
17      01      01      00      1.8   -8.2
17      01      01      00      1.8   -8.2
17      01      01      00      6.3   -8.1
17      01      01      00      1.2   -8.1
17      01      01      00      2.1   -8.0
17      01      01      00      2.0   -8.0
17      01      01      00      7.9   -8.0
EOF
#---------------------------------

# DESIRED OUTPUT

cat << EOF > ofile.txt
YY,MM,DD,HH,MIN,A,B,
17,01,01,03,00,3.3,-6.06,
17,01,01,03,10,2.3,-7.8,
17,01,01,03,20,3.13,-7.9,
17,01,01,03,30,4.3,-8.0,
17,01,01,03,40,4.4,-8.1,
17,01,01,03,50,4.4,-8.1,
17,01,01,04,00,1.8,-8.2,
17,01,01,04,10,1.8,-8.2,
17,01,01,04,20,6.3,-8.1,
17,01,01,04,30,1.8,-8.2,
17,01,01,04,40,1.8,-8.2,
17,01,01,04,50,6.3,-8.1,
17,01,01,05,00,1.2,-8.1,
17,01,01,05,10,2.1,-8.0,
17,01,01,05,20,2.0,-8.0,
17,01,01,05,30,7.9,-8.0,
EOF
#---------------------------------------

#My Script

cat << EOF > ofile.txt
YY,MM,DD,HH,MIN,A,B,
EOF

add_hr=3
add_min=00
n1=1
n2=$(wc -l < ifile.txt)
while [ $n1 -le $n2 ]
do

datetime="20170101 0000"
timestamp=$(date -d "$datetime" +%s)

new_timestamp=$((timestamp + add_hr * 3600 + add_min * 60))
new_datetime=$(date -d @$new_timestamp +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

DATE=$(echo "$new_datetime" | awk '{print substr($0,1,8)}')
YY=$(echo "${DATE}" | awk '{print substr($0,3,2)}')
MM=`date -d "${DATE}" "+%m"`
DD=`date -d "${DATE}" "+%d"`

HH=$(echo "$new_datetime" | awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}')
Min=$(echo "$new_datetime" | awk '{print substr($0,11,2)}')

A=$(awk 'NR=='$n1' {print $5}' ifile.txt)
B=$(awk 'NR=='$n1' {print $6}' ifile.txt)


cat << EOF >> ofile.txt
$YY,$MM,$DD,$HH,$Min,$A,$B,
EOF
add_min=$((add_min+10))
(( n1++ ))
done
```

Comment: does your timezone have daylight saving?

Comment: No.. it is simply 3 hours ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Weather this script will update the Day, Month, and Year accordingly?

Comment: Thanks again. But what about the YY-MM-DD-HH-MIN? Data is actually in this format. So e.g. for the date `17-12-31-23`, it should be considered as `18-01-01-02-00`

Comment: Your sample output has commas not hyphens. Perl's strftime handles date changes due to adding/subtracting hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: No no, there is no hyphen. I used here to explain only..

Comment: Please separate your input, output and code into 3 Code Blocks instead of cramming it all into 1 where we need a scroll bar to see them and can't see them all at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU awk has `strftime` / `mktime`:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { print "YY,MM,DD,HH,MIN,A,B," }
    {
        fmt = "%y,%m,%d,%H,%M,"$5","$6","
        datespec = "20"$1" "$2" "$3" "($4+3)" "(min+0)" 0"
        print strftime(fmt, mktime(datespec,1), 1)
        min += 10
    }
' ifile.txt >ofile.txt
```

A Perl solution is also quite short:

```
TZ=UTC perl -MPOSIX=strftime -aE '
    BEGIN { say "YY,MM,DD,HH,MIN,A,B," }
    say strftime "%y,%m,%d,%H,%M,$F[4],$F[5],",
        0, $min, $F[3]+3, $F[2], $F[1]-1, $F[0]+100;
    $min += 10
' ifile.txt >ofile.txt
```

Perl's `-a` option autosplits input lines on whitespace (like awk) and stores the pieces in array `@F`.

`strftime` arguments are: **fmt**, **sec**, **min**, **hour**, **mday**, **mon**, **year**.

**mon** is zero-based (January = 0). **year** counts from 1900.

Since dates will overlap daylight-savings, timezone should be set to a locale that doesn't use them.

Comment: gawk is convenient for. Thank you. I also want to add sqrt($5,$6) as 7th column. But it seems different to awk script. Would you please help me, how can I add this? I added, but printing sqrt($5,$6)

Comment: I did it. I had to add "" .. THank you very much